# Exit handler function (atexit) not updating arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, atexit

I am using atexit python module to disconnect some connected devices to my server when it is terminated (for example with Ctrl+C).

```
def exit_handler(csms):
    print(f"CSMS CONNECTED CHARGERS: {csms._chargers.items()}")
    for cp, task in csms._chargers.items():
        print(cp.id)
        try:
            csms.disconnect_charger(cp.id)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Failed to disconnect charger: {e}")
```

I am registering the exit handler like this:

```
csms = CentralSystem()

atexit.register(exit_handler, csms)
```

As you can see the exit handler function receives a "csms" as argument, this object has dictionary (_charger) which lists another object "cp" and an asyncio task. When I register the exit handler this dictionary is empty but then it is filled with the connected devices. However when I terminate the process and "csms._chargers" in the exit handler it shows that is empty, when it shouldn't be.
Any idea why this happens?

Comment: The naming ``_chargers`` suggests you are accessing an implementation detail. Are you sure it behaves as you expect, e.g. that it is always the same dict or not automatically cleared on shutdown?

Comment: I have to acces this variable in other parts of the script just as I did there and had no problems so far, I'm aware the name convention suggests this shouldn't be changed, but it is necessary for my application. When a device is required to be disconnected the same function (`disconnect_charger()`) is also used, what it does is basicly cancel the task.